# hook_preprocess_node() or hook_node_view() for html altering the field

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

What's the best way to alter html of an image field? I have imagefield and i want to rewrite it's html from scratch.

Comment: Some more detailed information on the markup changes you want to do would allow people to give you a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 3):

[hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) will do the job,

You may also take a look at writing your own `theme_image_formatter()`

It could work in a node_view() but you want to alter the FIELD's HTML.In node_view you would alter the order of fields, hide/show new contents NOT control how they look.. you could absolutely do it, but it will not be the best/Drupal way.

Drupal divides functionality (node_view()) and looks (theme)

In a hook_preprocess_node() you would alter the node template variables, not the field's ones.You would need it to add a class to a node wrapper, to change node templates etc...
you have to go deeper in the theme for this one.

**Examples:**

```
// ALL IMAGES get rounded class.
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  $variables['attributes']['class'] = array('rounded');
}
```

and for field

```
// If field_images in FULL view mode of a node, add/edit variables and choose template
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_images' && $element['#bundle'] == 'YOUR_NODE_TYPE' && $element['#view_mode'] == 'full') {
 $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'field__field_images_YOUR-file-name';
  // Add more variables available in template...
  $variables['toggle'] = 'Read the story';
  $variables['some_text'] = 'Some text';

}
```

Comment: Image is theme_image() not image.tpl.php so you can't do hook_reprocess_image() out of the box.

Comment: you can hook to any theme hook with hook_preprocess_HOOK, whats the template got to do with it?

Comment: Why hook_node_view() won't work?

Comment: Answered your comment in my answer

Comment: Oh whoops sorry, I don't know why I thought that. It's still possibly not as useful to the OP as overriding theme_image(), although we don't really have any information on what the markup changes are so we can't really know.